# Editor capabilities - admin_init

Tags: php, customization, admin-init

I'm having a little difficulties with roles and capabilities.

Editors gets a 'Cheatin uh?'-message when they try to update the custom theme-settings. Can anyone explain why - or maybe even have a solution?

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_global_custom_options');
function add_global_custom_options() {
add_menu_page('Indstillinger', 'Indstillinger', 'moderate_comments', 'functions','global_custom_options');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'custom_settings_css');
function custom_settings_css() {
wp_enqueue_style('custom-settings-css', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/theme-files/css/custom-settings.css');
} ?>

<?php
function global_custom_options()
{?>
<div class="wrap theme-options">
    <h2>Indstillinger</h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>

        <div class="section">
            <h3>Settings</h3>
            <p>
                <h4>BOXIT</h4>
                <textarea name="box1" size="45"><?php echo get_option('box1'); ?></textarea>
            </p>
        </div>

        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Gem indstillinger" /></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
        <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="box1" />
    </form>
</div>
<?php}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a capability called `edit_theme_options` which is by default assigned to only site admins not to editors. Check out - [Roles Vs Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) .

To allow your editors to manage theme options you've to manually assign that capability to editors.
Here to assign `edit_theme_options` capability to `editors` just drop in this code into your theme's `functions.php` file So editors can manage theme options page.

```
<?php

        function wpse61651_allow_editor() 
        {
            $role = get_role( 'editor' ); // pick up role to edit the editor role   
            $role->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' ); // Let them manage our theme
        }
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse61651_allow_editor');
?>
```

**Resource -**

- [Function Reference - Add Cap](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap)

Comment: Yeah, but as far as I know this 'Add Cap'-function only allows Editors to edit the native theme-option. And not my custom theme-options. I'm thinking that i might be hooking something wrong - no?

Comment: that's not true, if your're theme's options page check for non admin users by this capability it'd work.